# Update google play serivices for GoogleFit

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-fit

Hi i am trying out Google fit.when i run the app on emulator it show an dialog  that you need to update the play services to run the app but when i click on update nothing happens
my current version of Google play service on emulator is 5.0.53 and on installing using adb command it gives a duplicate certificate error ??
I am using Android L emulator and everything in the sdk manager is updated

Comment: Are you using the Android L emulator?

Comment: yes i am using L emulator and everything in the sdk manager is updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Google play services 5.2.08 (or later) and I don't think it is available in the emulator yet only on dev images for nexus 5 & 7. Hopefully the new version of google play services will be released to the public soon.

https://developers.google.com/fit/preview

Comment: Thanks a lot  zingo even I realised after going through the developer guide initially I directly jumped to api refrences